# GROUP ing data in PIG

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

I have data as follows 
name marks

```
ABC 2

ABC 3

ABC 3

XYZ 1

XYZ 2
```

I want o/p to be

```
ABC 8

XYZ 3
```

mY script is as:-

```
groupdata = GROUP filedata by name;

sumdata =FOREACH groupdata GENERATE filedata.name,SUM(filedata.marks);

DUMP sumdata;

i am getting o/p as

({ABC,ABC,ABC},8)

({XYZ,XYZ},3)
```

what is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  keyword `'group'` instead of `filedata.name`

```
sumdata = FOREACH groupdata GENERATE group,SUM(filedata.marks);
DUMP sumdata;
```